# Go: difference between any and interface in varargs

Tags: go, generics, any

In Golang 1.18 I can do this:

```
func foo1[T any](items ...T) {
    // do something
}

func foo2(items ...interface{}) {
    // do something
}
```

Both of these appear to accept a list of objects whose type is not known by the function itself. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: The main difference in **varargs** is that `...T` is **one** type, and after instantiation `foo1` will accept an arbitrary number of params of the same type. Whereas `...interface{}` accepts an arbitrary number of possibly different types, since all types can be assigned to the empty interface. For all other intents and purposes, `any` is a type alias of `interface{}`